# What is the best alternative way of monitoring apache Active MQ other than using JMX API

Tags: apache, api, monitoring, jmx, activemq-classic

I have tried and tested the JMX API and it is pretty simple to use and provides a vast number of statistics required for monitoring ActiveMQ.

But the problem is, i dont want to monitor my ActiveMQ remotely and also i dont want to use another API.To be more precise, i want to use the JMS API itself to get statistics related to various destinations and the broker itself.

Advisory messages seem to be an alternative but they provide limited Amount of Administrative Messages to monitor.

Any input is highly appreciated...

Comment: The JMS API is not intended for monitoring or management, that's what JMX is for.

Comment: There are methods to get DestinationStatistics which give complete details about the Destination, but all of the require a Broker Instance and i did not find any way to get the instance of the current Broker...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this. But you can implement a JMS topic which publishes the monitoring data every few seconds. Make the connection non-persistent so that it doesn't pile up when there are no listeners or when they loose connection.

Now you can write a client that connects to this topic and it will receive updates.

Answer (score 3):

AMQ-2379 resulted in a broker plugin for grabbing statistics from destinations by sending a simple JMS message. Check out the docs that show how to use it here:

http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html

The statistics plugin is available in the 5.3 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this http://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/AMQ-2379, it will be avaiable in upcoming 5.3.0 release

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post queued up to go on  http://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/AMQ-2379 - will post it in a couple of days or so